# How to install enterpeise app correctely?

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-functions

I have an enterprise app that I am trying to install on my device by hitting a URL, it starts downloading but fails after some time, and i don't even see App Icon while it's loading.

Well, that maybe because I didn't add two images URL with `57 X 57` and `512 x 512` in manifest.plist file. But i also removed thatsection from plist instead of providing empty values.

> Below are the things that i verified in plist-:
>
> 1) Correct application version. 2) Correct bundle identifier. 3)
>   Correct URL path to .IPA file.

We are using Azure Blob containers as a backend to keep .IPA and manifest file.

> I have verified my generated build with below option-:
>
> 1) Diawi: It's installing IPA fine and the application is running
>   fine. 2) iTunes-: Tried running .IPA with iTunes it's working. 3) App
>   Configurator 2 -: Working fine.

We have an Azure function in the backend which consists of HTML code, that opens a web page where we have a button to click which start the installation, and i have specified the correct manifest file URL to that URL.

I am not getting what's going wrong. Can anyone help? Please let me know if some other information is required.

Comment: Check the device logs to see why it's failing, it's hard to say this way what went wrong.

Comment: @Adis yeah that was helpful, i got the issue. Thanks